# CastaliaResults to plot graphs

Tags: omnet++

I am learning to use Castalia for WSN simulation.

I realized that in the user manual, the `YYYYMMDD` serial number that has been referred to in the examples of obtaining the `CastaliaResults` was "100809-004640.txt".

However, in the `CastaliaPlot` to plot the graph, a new number "101209-235427.txt" is being referred to.

Can anybody help with the source of this new number in Castalia 3.2 manual?

Answer (score 0):

As you realised the output files are named with a YYMMDD-HHmmss.txt convention
The name of the actual file does not matter much. They are used as examples in the manual. Obviously you will not have the same filenames when trying out the commands on your own.

In the specific example you mention, it would be better (more consistent) if the manual used the same filename, but it does not matter much.

I wrote the manual. I do not remember exactly what I did all these years back, but the simple explanation for the new filename is that I was rewriting only that part of the manual (the graphs part), so I used some more recent output files to draw the graphs. Probably you can find instances of this minor inconsistency in other places in the manual as well.